# Cannot invoke initializer for type with no arguments - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm moving from objective-c to swift and all i'm trying to do is simply create an instance of class so that I can access a property on said class.

```
var myClassInstance = MyClass()

print("length is \(myClassInstance.variableOne)")
```

something in that regard but I'm getting an error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MyClass' with no arguments`

Comment: Does your `MyClass` have an `init` method?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it does have an init method `init(origin: CGPoint) { ... }`

Comment: You're not supplying it with a `CGPoint`, hence your error. Supply a `CGPoint`, or write an initializer that doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Then you have to call `MyClass(origin:...)` and pass a `CGPoint` to the constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create class like below:

```
class MyClass{
var variableOne:CGPoint

    init(variableOne: CGPoint) {
        self.variableOne = variableOne
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(variableOne: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    }
}


var myClassInstance = MyClass()
print("Default length is \(myClassInstance.variableOne)")

var myClassInstance2 = MyClass(variableOne: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
print("length is \(myClassInstance2.variableOne)")
```

Comment: I added `init(variableOne: CGPoint) { self.variableOne = length }` to MyClass but now get a new error saying `Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer`