# ReachabilitySwift pod causes an error in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, reachability, swift2

I'm using [ReachabilitySwift cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=ReachabilitySwift) in project.

**Pod file :**

```
pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 2.4'
```

I installed this pod and imported `ReachabilitySwift` file.

Now, when creating an instance  `let reachability = Reachability()!`
results in error **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Reachability' with no arguments.**

[image: Screenshot]

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948824/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-with-no-arguments-swift) but didn't worked.

Any fix?

Comment: Can you show how you apply ReachabilitySwift in pod file. Did you limited its version?

Comment: @Sergey : Check updated question

Comment: Please look on my answer, I already found answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fix!

Reachability instance to be created as follow for Swift 2.3

```
let reachability = try! Reachability.init(hostname: "www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

**You have to use one of the initializers taking an argument.**

Type `let reachability =  Reach` and figure out what Xcode suggests in code completion
 (or read the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use **swift 2.3**, for this version you need to use **ReachabilitySwift** with version **2.4**. But in this version **Reachability** class don't a have constructor without parameters. To fixe this you need to create extension for this class and add constructor without parameters.

```
extansion Reachability{
   public convenience init() {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr()
        zeroAddress.sa_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr>.size)
        zeroAddress.sa_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let ref: SCNetworkReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }) else { return nil }

        self.init(reachabilityRef: ref)
    }
}
```

I don't tested this code. It's code can contains some errors.